# Is it possible to get UNIX time from such date 2011-02-27 02:04:46?

Tags: php

Mktime and other functions give wrong answer for such a date like 2011-02-27 02:04:46;

Comment: http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: [PHP Reference: Date and time functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php)

Comment: Please use the search function before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=date+to+timestamp+php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the [**`strtotime()`**](https://www.php.net/strtotime) function, or the [**`DateTime`**](https://www.php.net/datetime) class.

Both the two following portions of code :

```
echo strtotime('2011-02-27 02:04:46');

$dt = new DateTime('2011-02-27 02:04:46');
echo $dt->format('U');
```

Will give you the same output :

```
1298768686
```

Answer (score 2):

Use strtotime

```
$time = '2011-02-27 02:04:46';
strtotime($time);
```

Comment: Why the date() call? strtotime already returns a PHP time value, which is a unix timestamp.

Comment: my bad, just copied and pasted from a script where I'd used strtotime to convert from one time format to another (not UNIX)

Answer (score 1):

This will also work (if you need this to run from the unix shell):

```
date +%T
```

This will show the time like:

```
14:20:18
```