# Time string to timestamp

Tags: php, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to get UNIX time from such date 2011-02-27 02:04:46?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749319/is-it-possible-to-get-unix-time-from-such-date-2011-02-27-020446)

How can I convert a PHP timestamp like `2011-05-04 10:35:57` to Unix epoch time (in seconds)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime("2011-05-04 10:35:57")`