# How to get a unix timestamp from DateTime object with PHP 5.2?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm working on a few years old codebase and it uses DateTime. The server is using **PHP 5.2**.

I see that **DateTime::getTimestamp()** has been added after **PHP 5.3**.

Is it possible to get a timestamp from DateTime in **PHP 5.2**?

I used get_class_methods to see if the method is available, but it's not.

```
Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => format
    [2] => modify
    [3] => getTimezone
    [4] => setTimezone
    [5] => getOffset
    [6] => setTime
    [7] => setDate
    [8] => setISODate
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get UNIX time from such date 2011-02-27 02:04:46?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749319/is-it-possible-to-get-unix-time-from-such-date-2011-02-27-020446)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
echo $datetime->format('U');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6ZxvwI)

**edit**

As of PHP 5.4 you can make this a one-liner:

```
echo (new DateTime())->format('U');
```

Comment: I hate it, that it's not possible with one line of code. Something like this `(new DateTime())->format('U')`, grrr...

Comment: @algorhythm You can do that in PHP 5.4+

Answer (score 3):

> Using U as the parameter to DateTime::format() is an alternative when
>   using PHP 5.2.

```
$ts = $datetimeObj->format('U');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would take a look at the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

> Using U as the parameter to DateTime::format() is an alternative when
>   using PHP 5.2.

So `DateTime::format('U')` it is.